# scope.$watch does not get triggered after scope.$digest in karma unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to test this directive:

```
.directive('mwIcon', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      mwIcon: '@',
      tooltip: '@',
      placement: '@',
      style: '@'
    },
    template: '<i ng-class="iconClasses" style="{{style}}" mw-tooltip="{{tooltip}}" placement="{{placement}}"></i>',
    link: function (scope, el) {

      el.addClass('mw-icon');
      //set icon classes
      scope.$watch('mwIcon', function (newVal) {
        if (newVal) {
          var isFontAwesome = angular.isArray(scope.mwIcon.match(/^fa-/)),
            isRlnIcon = angular.isArray(scope.mwIcon.match(/rln-icon/));
          if (isFontAwesome) {
            scope.iconClasses = 'fa ' + scope.mwIcon;
          } else if (isRlnIcon) {
            scope.iconClasses = 'rln-icon ' + scope.mwIcon;
          } else {
            scope.iconClasses = 'glyphicon glyphicon-' + scope.mwIcon;
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
})
```

Specifically what happens when I change `scope.mwIcon`. It should change the class of the `<i>` element as well, since `scope.mwIcon` has a watcher, right? This is my test:

```
it('should change the class according to the new icon', function () {
  var icon = '<span mw-icon="search"></span>';
  var el = $compile(icon)(scope);
  scope.$digest();

  expect(el.children().hasClass("glyphicon")).toBe(true);
  expect(el.children().hasClass("glyphicon-search")).toBe(true);

  scope.mwIcon = "fa-star";
  scope.$digest();

  expect(el.children().hasClass("fa")).toBe(true);
  expect(el.children().hasClass("fa-star")).toBe(true);
});
```

The bottom two assertions return false, even though I triggered a change of `scope.mwIcon` with `scope.$digest`. Any ideas why my `<i>` element still has classes "glyphicon glyphicon-search" and not "fa fa-star"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the directive is using an isolated scope. When setting the new `mwIcon` on the isolated scope, the test works.

```
it('should change the class according to the new icon', function () {
  var icon = '<span mw-icon="search"></span>';
  var el = $compile(icon)(scope);
  var isolatedScope = el.isolateScope();

  scope.$digest();

  expect(el.children().hasClass("glyphicon")).toBe(true);
  expect(el.children().hasClass("glyphicon-search")).toBe(true);

  isolatedScope.mwIcon = "fa-star";
  scope.$digest();

  expect(el.children().hasClass("fa")).toBe(true);
  expect(el.children().hasClass("fa-star")).toBe(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding mwIcon to an attribute string (with @), so subsequently setting scope.mwIcon, won't trigger the $watch. You can either change it to a two-way binding (mwIcon: '=',) or try using attr.$observe instead, with attrs added as the third arg to your link function, though I haven't tried this last approach.

Comment: I can't change the directive just to make the test pass.